What is $j_\mathcal{U}(\kappa)$ if $2^{\kappa}<j_\mathcal{U}(\kappa)<(2^{\kappa})^{+}$?
Let $\mathcal{U}$ a non-principal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$ and let $j_\mathcal{U}\colon V\to M$ its associated elementary embedding of the universe $V$ in $M=Ult_\mathcal{U}(V)$. In lemma 17.9 (iii), Jech proves that $2^{\kappa}\leq (2^{\kappa})^{M}<j_\mathcal{U}(\kappa)<(2^{\kappa})^{+}$. So in particular we have $2^{\kappa}<j_\mathcal{U}(\kappa)<(2^{\kappa})^{+}$.
Because $j_\mathcal{U}$ is an elementary embedding and $\kappa$ is a cardinal, then $j_\mathcal{U}(\kappa)$ is a cardinal too. But between $2^{\kappa}$ and $(2^{\kappa})^{+}$ there are no cardinals. So what cardinal is $j_\mathcal{U}(\kappa)$?

$j_\mathcal{U}(\kappa)$ is a cardinal of $M,$ not a cardinal of $V.$

Okay, it makes sense now, thanks for your answer!
